# RVEST scraping from hex unicode page, cannot grep() backslash to clean data

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, ascii, rvest

I am using `rvest` to scrape data from footballsquads.co.uk, which I believe is an openware site.  Initial code below using **R**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

TFC <- read_html("http://www.footballsquads.co.uk/usa/2016/mls/toronto.htm") %>%
          html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/table') %>%
          html_table()
```

Some accented letters transfer over naturally `TFC[14,2]: Clément Simonin`, I am having trouble cleaning up the encoding on a few players' names, like `Benoît Cheyrou`, which I believe to be hex-unicode based:

```
> TFC[9,2]
[1] "Beno\xeet Cheyrou"
```

Any `grep()` function I've tried (i.e. `'xee'`), hasn't isolated the `\xee` unicode string I'm trying to replace with `î`, which makes me think this is an encoding issue. Tried the escape double-backslash and got this:

```
> grep('\\\xee',TFC$X2)
integer(0)
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have been recently notified that this is in fact ASCII and not unicode. I'm new to web scraping so I don't really know one way or the other.

Comment: Have you tried `grep('\\\\xeee',TFC$X2)` That is with four "\"?

Comment: Yup and `integer(0)`